# How does pretty json works?

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I am new to django-tastypie. When I try create the API using following code,

```
class PrettyJSONSerializer(Serializer):
    json_indent = 4

        def to_json(self, data, options=None):
            print '.................'
            options = options or {}
            data = self.to_simple(data, options)
            return simplejson.dumps(data, cls=json.DjangoJSONEncoder,
                                    sort_keys=True, ensure_ascii=False, indent=self.json_indent)


    class ShipmentResource(ModelResource):
        class Meta:
            queryset = Shipment.objects.all()
            serializer = PrettyJSONSerializer()
```

And it gives the output shown below,

```
{"shipments": [{"awb_bol": "AWB#6", "carrier": "Yellow", "etd_eta": "2013-04-14", "from_to": "KKD-HYD", "id": 1, "mode": "Transport", "pieces": "10.00", "po": "PO-123", "resource_uri": "/api/shipment/1/", "status": "W", "weight": "25.00", "wr": "WR-123"}, {"awb_bol": "BWAB", "carrier": "Green", "etd_eta": "2013-04-23", "from_to": "AMP-HYD", "id": 3, "mode": "Transport", "pieces": "1.30", "po": "OP-123", "resource_uri": "/api/shipment/3/", "status": "O", "weight": "1.40", "wr": "RW 45"}]}
```

But I need to above output this formate only,

```
{
    "shipments": [
        {
            "awb_bol": "AWB#6",
            "carrier": "Yellow",
            "etd_eta": "2013-04-14",
            "from_to": "KKD-HYD",
            "id": 1,
            "mode": "Transport",
            "pieces": "10.00",
            "po": "PO-123",
            "resource_uri": "/api/shipment/1/",
            "status": "W",
            "weight": "25.00",
            "wr": "WR-123"
        },
        {
            "awb_bol": "BWAB",
            "carrier": "Green",
            "etd_eta": "2013-04-23",
            "from_to": "AMP-HYD",
            "id": 3,
            "mode": "Transport",
            "pieces": "1.30",
            "po": "OP-123",
            "resource_uri": "/api/shipment/3/",
            "status": "O",
            "weight": "1.40",
            "wr": "RW 45"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is any default functionalities available in In django-tastypie. 
Please solve my problem. Thanks..

Comment: These are equivalent...

Comment: Thanks for reply. In my browser I have seen json formate contains no new lines(i.e;It is linear formate). But I need to json formate with new lines.

Comment: It's usually your browser's job to format JSON as needed. If you use Chrome, the [JSONView](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc) extension does it well. I'm sure there's an equivalent for other browsers. Or do you have a specific need for your JSON to contain new lines ?

Answer (score 0):

To simplejson.dumps add separators=[',',': '] parameter

```
return simplejson.dumps(data, cls=json.DjangoJSONEncoder, sort_keys=True, ensure_ascii=False, indent=self.json_indent, separators=[',',': '])
```

This work fine with standard python json library but for their similarity I think it's same.

To avoid wrong response to the page I would recommend you to add content_type='application/json' to page response.